# How can I produce random single precision floating point numbers in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to verify behavior of a floating point multiplier using Universal Verification Methodology and I have an issue.
The problem is that when I want to generate single precision floating point numbers. Basically, This not possible directly and I decided to generate two random 32 bit numbers like following:

```
rand logic [31:0] A;
rand logic [31:0] B;
```

The issue is now we may produce many numbers which basically are not valid numbers in IEEE754 notation.
My question is that how can I put correct constraints for these numbers and what are those constraints?

Comment: can you define an invalid number? How can you violate the standard in this case? It only defines the number of significant and exponent bits.

Comment: Possibly means that randomizing the bit pattern will generate NaN's and infinities

Answer (score -1):

Systemverilog allows randomization in terms of integer/logic/bit vector values (NOT real floating pt). Rationale being! it would slowdown processor/server speeds to generate fractional values.  What you may want to do is constrain the random int variable and multiply it to the real type number for your use case.

```
 class temp;
    rand int multi_x;
    real w, y;
 endclass

module mytest;

temp tt = new();

initial begin
    tt.w=3.2345;
    for(int j=0; j<4;j++)begin
        std::randomize(tt);
        tt.y= tt.w *(real'(tt.multi_x));
        $display("Value tt.y = %f, val tt.w=%f, val tt.multi_x=%f", tt.y, tt.w,tt.multi_x);
    end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: I do not see how this could help verification effort. Hardware does not operate verilog's real data types.

Comment: The thing I was trying to was to apply some constraints to random generated 32 bit numbers and make them random floating point numbers. However, I have to figure out how to add this code my project.